# Django orm subquery - in clause without substitution

Tags: django, django-orm

I need to build a query using Django ORM, that looks like this one in SQL:

```
select * from A where id not in (select a_id from B where ... )
```

I try to use such code:

```
ids = B.objects.filter(...)
a_objects = A.object.exclude(id__in=Subquery(ids.values('a__id'))).all()
```

The problem is that instead of nested select Django generates query that looks like

```
select * from A where id not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ....)
```

where in clause explicitly lists all ids that should be excluded, making result sql unreadable when it is printed into logs. Is it possible to adjst this query, so nested select is used?

Comment: Being unreadable isn't the only problem with such query. It is also about poor performance on large amounts of objects.

Comment: That's surprising. This code should indeed generate a subquery. Could you please provide a simple concrete example (ideally reproducible). I'm afraid the simplified generic code you provided might lack some specific context or subtleties that affect the result. It would also be interesting to know your Django version, the database backend, and whether `str(a_objects.query)` shows the subquery or an evaluated values list (independently of the actual executed query).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I see that your goal is to get all the A's that have no foreign key relations from B's. If I'm right, then you can just use inverse lookup to do it.

So, when you define models like that:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    a = ForeignKey(to=a, related_name='bs')
```

You can filter it like this:

```
A.objects.filter(bs__isnull=True)
```

Also, if you don't define `related_name`, it will default to `b_set`, so you will be able to `A.objects.filter(b_set__isnull=True)`

Answer (score 0):

to make a filter on B you can

```
ids  = B.objects.filter(x=x).values_list('id',flat=true)
```

you get a list of ids then make

```
a_objects = A.object.exclude(id__in=ids)
```

as mentioned before if there is a relation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special, just use the queryset directly in your filter.

```
ids = B.objects.filter(...)
a_objects = A.object.exclude(id__in=ids).all()

# that should generate the subquery statement
select * from A where NOT (id in (select a_id from B where ... ))
```